# Criteria with "in" operator and empty list

Tags: java, hibernate

I have next problem.

I have next criteria:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("entity.otherEntity", getOtherEntitiesList()));
```

if my otherEntitiesList is empty. Hibernate generate next query:

```
select count(*) as y0_ 
from OTHER_ENTITY this_ 
where this_.OTHER_ENTITY_ID in ( )
```

and i get exception from Oracle.

I found next line in Hibernate code:

```
 String params = values.length > 0 ? StringHelper.repeat(
                singleValueParam + ", ", values.length - 1 )
                + singleValueParam : "";
```

It's not possible use this method to generate criteria.
I need a way to generate Hibernate criteria with empty list. If list is empty I want to get empty answer.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: If the list is empty, there shouldn't be a result, so just return an empty list without making a query.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you check the list size first and then create a restriction (if the size is `> 0`):

```
if (getOtherEntitiesList() != null && getOtherEntitiesList().size() > 0) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("entity.otherEntity", getOtherEntitiesList()));
}
```

Comment: Or just return zero without a DB hit.

Comment: I need criteria that return nothing.
But I not want write something like criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("Id",-1L)).add(Restrictions.eq("Id",-1L)))

Comment: In your example, criteria will return all rows from table.

Comment: That's right. Just add an `else` statement, where you can implement the logic when the list is empty (possibly you need to return zero without a DB hit, as Suresh Atta mentioned).

Comment: Yes i can. But I have criteria constructed from 30 parameters not all from them lists. I need return criteria from method and in case criteria.add(Restrictions.in("entity.otherEntity", getOtherEntitiesList())).add(
                    Restrictions.gt("endDate", endDate)).add(
                    Restrictions.lt("startDate", startDate)); I want empty answer.

Comment: I want that class that uses my criteria received empty answer.